# Getting started with NOAA conus_bref_qcd calls

Tags: php, noaa, radar

I'm trying to take advantage of the NOAA radar APIs to create a JPG/PNG image of the radar situation centered around a certain lat/lng coordinate.  I've tried looking at the documentation [here](https://preview-opengeo.ncep.noaa.gov/geoserver/www/index.html) for the BREF QCD service, but I seem to be missing something.  I tried sniffing the network on radar.weather.gov and came up with URLs like the one below, but I keep getting errors in my bounding box.  The URL below gives me the message:

> 400: The bounding box parameter (-7894188.2926589,5561066.4766705,-7890993.4232736,5557876.8552164) is missing or not sane

`https://opengeo.ncep.noaa.gov/geoserver/conus/conus_bref_qcd/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&TILED=true&LAYERS=conus_bref_qcd&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=512&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&TIME=2023-10-17T02%3A04%3A04.000Z&BBOX=-7894188.2926589%2C5561066.4766705%2C-7890993.4232736%2C5557876.8552164`

I'm attempting to convert my lat/lng coordinates to EPSG=3857 with the function at the bottom of this post, but I can't seem to figure out the appropriate size for the BBOX.  I'm really just looking for either a guide to get me started or someone to tell me that generating an image manually is nuts and I should be using some library or another.

```
    function convertEPSG4326to3857($nLat, $nLng) {
        $x = $nLng;
        $y = $nLat;
        
        $x = ($x * 20037508.34) / 180;
        $y = (log(tan(((90 + $y) * pi()) / 360)) / (pi() / 180));
        $y = ($y * 20037508.34) / 180;
    
        return [$x, $y];
    }
```